# Modify Wordpress plugin to show posts by category instead of id#

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am using this Wordpress plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/carousel-of-post-images/
It shows a slider of posts & displays the featured image.
It is currently set to show posts by id which need to be individually entered into the shortcode. Is it possible to show posts by category instead so that I can set the category of the post and see only that category in the slider?

Here is all the code that I believe is responsible.

```
function copi_carousel_get_images($size = 'medium' , $orderby, $posts, $count, $class = ''){
global $post;

$att_array = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'orderby' => $orderby, 
    'numberposts' => $count,
    );

$postlist = explode(",",$posts);
$sizes = explode(",", $size);
$html = '';
if (count($sizes) == 2)
{
    $width = $sizes[0];
    $height = $sizes[1];
    $size=$sizes;
}
else
{
    $width = get_option($size.'_size_w');
    $height = get_option($size.'_size_h');
}

foreach($postlist as $postid)
{
    if ($postid != '')
        $att_array['post_parent'] = $postid;

    $attachments = get_posts($att_array);

    if (is_array($attachments)){
        foreach($attachments as $att){
            $image_src_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($att->ID, $size);
            $url = $image_src_array[0];
            if ($url != "")
            {

                $prefix = '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($att->post_parent).'">';
                $suffix = "</a></li>";

                $caption = $att->post_excerpt;

                if(function_exists('thumbGen'))
                    $url = thumbGen($url, $width, $height, 'return=1');

                $image_html = '<img src="%s" height="'.$height.'" alt="%s">';

                $html .= $prefix.sprintf($image_html,$url,$caption,$class).$suffix;
            }
        }
    }
}
return  $html;

}

function show_wp_copi_carousel($atts){
    $skin = 'tango';
    $div='post-carousel';
    $imagesize = 'medium';
    $orderby = 'rand';
    $postid = '';
    $count='10';

if (isset($atts['skin'])) 
    $skin = $atts['skin'];

if (isset($atts['imagesize'])) 
    $imagesize = $atts['imagesize'];

if (isset($atts['orderby'])) 
    $orderby = $atts['orderby'];

if (isset($atts['postid'])) 
    $postid = $atts['postid'];

if (isset($atts['count'])) 
{
    $count = $atts['count'];
```

Comment: Hi, although quite old, this post didn't get a reply from the author of the plugin: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-carousel-of-post-images-category-instead-of-postid-is-it-possible this suggests that this functionality is not easy to implement in this plugin. I would suggest looking for an alternative instead of trying to re-write this plugin.

Comment: Thank you, I have looked at the support forum for the plugin & the last post that is on there is 3 months old & no reply, it is a fairly simple request leading me to believe that the developer does not pay much attention to support. I could be wrong but no reply from the author does not to me "suggest that this functionality is not easy to implement in this plugin". If it is, so be it but I have already spent a lot of time looking for an alternative with no luck, this plugin comes closest to doing what I need.

Comment: Sure, sometimes the authors of plugins just miss posts or do not reply for other reasons... But I had a look in the support forum and also saw this http://wordpress.org/support/topic/images-from-custom-post-type-cpt which kind of suggests that it is not meant to be very customisable.

Answer (score 0):

I do this with Coda slider.

First include the script in the head:

```
<script src="js/jquery.coda-slider-3.0.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){

  /* Here is the slider using default settings */
  $('#slider-id').codaSlider({
        autoSlide:true,
        autoHeight:false
});

});

</script>
```

Then I used the loop:

```
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>

<div class="coda-slider"  id="slider-id">
<?php
$args = array('category' => 15, 'numberposts' => 4, 'order'=> 'ASC');
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>"/>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

This should work!

Note: To show post information, just include "the_post" in the loop or whatever content you want to display, the slider script will take care of the rotation.

Also, this needs to be used in a template.

Comment: Thank you, this is a bit beyond my skills however, I have made the template & the slider is functioning but I don't see the posts. I do not understand where "just include "the_post" in the loop" goes & I am not sure how this references the post category. I am specifically looking for a way to have more than one of these sliders on the page , each one referencing a specific post category.

Comment: @Cormac I understand, the wordpress "Loop" can be tricky if you're not familiar with templates or PHP. Any plugin you find will utilize the loop in its source to generate a listing of posts or content. Feel free to email me and maybe I can help you out more. buckmcgrane@gmail.com